# Why I can't access as json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a array on `test.php` like this .

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => nikhil
        [password] => 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => akhil
        [password] => 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
    )
)
```

I convert it into JSON and echo it

```
$jsonformat = json_encode($array);
echo $jsonformat;
```

Then I get a JSON string like this on `test.php`

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "nikhil",
    "password": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "akhil",
    "password": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055"
}]
```

Now how can I access this string as JSON using an AJAX call. I want to access only name of 1st row of this JSON object. I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/test.php',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result[0].name);
    }
});
```

But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you reach the `success` function (is your json valid...)? If so, what does `result` contain, `console.log(result);`?

Comment: `success : function(result){
            var data = $.parseJSON(result);
alert(data.name);} // or try once alert(data[0].name)
    });`

Comment: By the way, you probably just need to change `datatype` to `dataType` to make sure jQuery automatically parses the returned json.

Comment: @jeroen If i just use alert(result);  It works fine and alert all json on screen correctly

Comment: You should get "object" there so that means the json is not parsed. See my previous comment.

Comment: @jeroen  Thanks T works ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. You set the data type to `json` so that jQuery knows what to expect back and parse it automatically.

However, the correct key for the data type is `dataType` and not `datatype`.

So you need:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/test.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result[0].name);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes it's correct. i have checked it, now code worked. +1